# How to import void ** C++ API into C#?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

In c++ API Declaration is

```
BOOL DCAMAPI dcam_attachbuffer          ( HDCAM h, void** top, _DWORD size );
```

arguments :
void** top--- is the array of pointer to buffer
_DWORD size-- is size of top parameter in bytes

In c#, this is how I import the dll file:

```
[DllImport("dcamapi.dll", EntryPoint = "dcam_attachbuffer",
          CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
          CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false,
          ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        [return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

   public static extern bool dcam_attachbuffer(IntPtr handleCamera,
 [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]ref Int32[] buf, 
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 bufsize);
```

My question is do I convert the type from c++ into c# correctly? and How do I declare void**in c#? please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is depending on what function dcam_attachbuffer do.

If it's taking buffer, define method

```
[DllImport("dcamapi.dll", EntryPoint = "dcam_attachbuffer"]
public static extern bool dcam_attachbuffer(
    IntPtr handleCamera,
    IntPtr ptrsBuf, 
    Int32 bufSize);
```

and pass pointer derived earlier.

If function is getting pointer of pointers, define method

```
[DllImport("dcamapi.dll", EntryPoint = "dcam_attachbuffer"]
public static extern bool dcam_attachbuffer(
    IntPtr handleCamera,
    ref IntPtr ptrsBuf, 
    Int32 bufSize);
```

and use

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(
    IntPtr source,
    IntPtr[] destination,
    int startIndex,
    int length
)
```

to copy pointers in IntPtr[]

Answer (score 2):

[You can declare pointers directly in C# in unsafe blocks.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx)

[There's also IntPtr.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx)

Or you can write some C++/CLI to glue the two together.

Comment: There are things that you can do with C++ that you can't do very easily with C#, but essentially yes, if you don't mind using `unsafe` code in your C# program, you can use pointers to certain types.

Answer (score 2):

The argument is IntPtr[] (no ref).  With the unnecessary attributes removed:

```
[DllImport("dcamapi.dll")]
public static extern bool dcam_attachbuffer(IntPtr handleCamera, 
    IntPtr[] buf, int bufsize);
```

Correctly initializing the array could be a challenge as well, it is quite unclear from the question what is required.

Comment: In c++ code 2nd argument is void** top is the array of pointer to buffer. my question is how to write this void** in c# is it with byte array or int array or Intptr???

Comment: Asked and answered.  You'll have to post sample C++ code that uses this function to narrow it down, void** is too vague.